# Data Ingest Timeout - Javascript / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, typescript

I would very much appreciate a better understanding in how to control the Javascript event loop.

I have a service that polls an ingest table every `n` seconds, extracts `i` records and runs them through a process to make them fit for consumption. This process seems to work well when both `n` is high (2000ms), and `i` is low (30). When I increase the polling frequency or the top number, the process twists itself in a knot, and all/many/most of the requests end up timing out.

I think it's because async/await just moves onto the next item in the same event loop and all the db commands queue up.

the code runs something like this:

```
//psudo code
async function doIngest(count){
  records = await selectTopFromIngest(count);

  for each record {
     schema = await getSchemaFromDatabase(record)
     isvalid = isValid(schema, record);
     data = await transformRecordIntoComplexData(record)
     if isValid { 
       await connection from pool
       await begin tran
       await insert data
       await insert sub record A
       await insert sub record B
       await insert sub record n...
       await commit tran
       result = pass
       triggerEvents > other listeners now want access to data
     }
     await closeIngestRecord(isValid)
  }
}
```

It looks to me like they want to stack, and you see

```
getSchemaFromDatabase, getSchemaFromDatabase, ... * 100 // (once for each record)
```

Then, as those complete they start to

```
transform, transform, transform, ... * 100
```

all the while there are still `getSchemaFromDatabase(...)` waiting, and they start to timeout.

Is there schema for doing something like this other than limiting the number of records and the polling? In addition, I find this difficult to debug/troubleshoot because of the volume required to get them to error. Some will work, and then I get hit in the face with 80 that failed. Any tips here would also be appreciated.

Comment: Which database are you using? It seems like database joins would be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Express 2019 for development.

Comment: Okay so just use joins: [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: I'm familiar with joins, and my database uses many of them. I fail to understand who using joins in the database helps me control the flow in JavaScript.

I think what I'm really running into here, is connection pool size of the mssql/msnodesqlv8. When I keep the `n` extracted below say 50 the pool doesn't get overloaded.